# double to float without rounding python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

say `a = 580991.3636`

When I `b = np.float32(a)`

b `580991.4`

I'm after b `580991.3636`

I'm hoping this is an easy one, any ideas?
I'm also assuming it is my misunderstanding of floats causing this.
I know python is dynamic when it comes to dtypes, but I need it to be in float32 for a specific library (python-pcl).

Comment: The closest float to 580991.3636 has exact value 580991.375 which would print as 580991.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float32 can only offer between 6 and 9 digits of precision.

Float32 works by storing the sign in 1 bit, the exponent in 8 bits and the value in 23 bits (also called the fraction). So you can represent a wide range of real numbers at the cost of precision.

If you need it to be more precise it has to be a double or use the python's library [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html).